# Reducing assets size on iOS with unity

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, build, compression, pvrtc

My android build size is 30mb, but my iOS build size (appstore size) is 400mb. After some researches, I found out that it may be because of assets compression. However, I found really old answers on the forum and I don't know what to do exactly.

I have several PNG images of the size 8192x1080 that I can't shrink because of the quality (I know this is big, but suppose there is no way to reduce or split it) :

[image]

What should I do ?

- Use a plugin ? Which one ?
- Create an AssetBundle ? I never used it.
- Make my images 8192x8192 ? When I do so, the size increase to 85mb.
- Don't use Sprite type but Advanced type?

An other question; when my image is not ARGB but RGB, the second warning message change from PVRTC to ETC1. What is the reason and consequence of it ?

Thanks for the help.

Comment: iOS size is wrong. It actually contains 32 and 64bit within the 400mb plus some Apple code optimization that will be removed on upload to the store. Still, the size of your image is simply ridiculous. Not the data size, the image size 8192. 1080 is no power of two so Unity is likely not to compress it properly (NPOT).

Comment: 1) 400mb is the appstore size. 2) Despite the size is ridiculous, it doesn't answer the question. What should I do but to change the image size?

Comment: Is it the appstore suze or the download size? Make your image smaller and power of two.

Comment: It is appstore size. If I make my images POT, there will be a big transparent area, and it weight 85mb in the unity interface. Will it be compress still ?

Comment: You should try to squeeze the image down to 1024 instead of 1080. Maybe working it out a bit. Second would be to downsize to 4096x512 You would lose a bit of precision but you would reduce the size by 4 plus it would compress.

Comment: Oh that's right, power of two doesn't mean square... I'm gonna go for this solution then. Thx.